# resuable jsonp request vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm learning object oriented programming and ran into an issue I'm not sure how to approach. I have a jsonp request hitting the 3rd party server when the user first lands on the page. There's another jsonp request that fires when the user uses the search field. As you can see I have duplicated code with the jsonp request. How would I refactor to make this reusable with the individual queries? Also, here is my attempt to make my code reusable, but with no success https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/

```
function defaultUrl() {
 return 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=mario&callback=appendResults'
}

var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = defaultUrl()

script.onload = function() {
 this.remove()
}

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.insertBefore(script, null)

var form = document.getElementById('search-container-form')
var searchField = document.getElementById('search').value

function makeUrl(query) {
 return `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=${query}&callback=appendResults`
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault()

var searchField = document.getElementById('search').value

if(searchField !== '') {
 var script = document.createElement('script')
 script.src = makeUrl(searchField)

script.onload = function() {
  this.remove
}

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.insertBefore(script, null)
}
})

window.appendResults = function(data) {
// manipulate data here 
}
```

Comment: create a function that accepts a URL as a parameter and does the jsonp thing

Comment: note ... `element.insertBefore(whatever, null);` is equivalent to `element.appendChild(whatever);`

Comment: I tried the function with a callback prior to writing this question. Here I try to attempt it again, but it will not work for some reason. I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure where the problem is. https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/

Comment: there's an error in the fiddle `appendresults` function, though I'm sure the code you tested has more to it than that

Comment: I see a potential issue in `getJSON` - if `searchField` is null, or undefined, or false or anything but an empty string, you'll be loading using `makeUrl` and probably not getting what you expect - [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/1/) seems to work, once I commented out code which will fail due to the lack of `form`

Comment: Actually, the code in `getJSON` was even more wrong - you were passing in a URL that was never used! [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/4/) is a demonstrably functioning version including a form

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. Can you elaborate on what you mean by, "you were passing in a URL that was never used?" In my fiddle for getJSON I wrote, script.src = defaultUrl() which should call the function defaultUrl with the returned url. Later I call getJSON passing in defaultUrl again. I understand now that this was completely wrong(setting script.url to defaultUrl), but it was making the call to a url that was defined the code as the default URL. Hopefully I'm not confusing things.